# links (hyperlink) inside pdf is removed when splitting multiple page pdf into different single page

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, fpdi

i was splitting pdf into different single page using fpdf and fpdi. Everything works fine but the link inside pdf was not working. Link was removed on splitted single pages.

```
split_pdf("test.pdf", 'splitedpdf/');

function split_pdf($filename, $end_directory = false)
{
    require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');

    $end_directory = $end_directory ? $end_directory : './';
    $new_path = preg_replace('/[\/]+/', '/', $end_directory.'/'.substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '/')));

    if (!is_dir($new_path))
    {
        // Will make directories under end directory that don't exist
        // Provided that end directory exists and has the right permissions
        mkdir($new_path, 0777, true);
    }

    $pdf = new FPDI();
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filename); // How many pages?

    // Split each page into a new PDF
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
        $new_pdf = new FPDI();
        $new_pdf->AddPage();
        $new_pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
        $new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($i));

        try {
            $new_filename = $end_directory.str_replace('.pdf', '', $filename).'_'.$i.".pdf";
            $new_pdf->Output($new_filename, "F");
            echo "Page ".$i." split into ".$new_filename."<br />\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
    //  $pdf->close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FPDI is not able to handle any dynamic content](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-links-are-gone/#question-204) link links, form fields or any other annotation type. There's [an extension](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2020422) which support at least links (only compatible with FPDI 1.4.4 + FPDF_TPL 1.2.3).

If you need to extract the pages including all attached annotations, you may check out the [SetaPDF-Merger component](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-merger/demos/split/) (not free!).

Comment: is there any free api or library ??
i just need pdf to be split with its external links

Comment: I just tried it my own and confirm, that the version will not work with the current version of FPDI but with version 1.4.4 + FPDF_TPL (v1.2.3). I updated my answer.